# how Can I use css modules and global style together on React

Tags: css, reactjs, module, styles, classname

i want to use normal class and module class together.
if i use two className it says "JSX elements cannot have multiple attributes with the same name."

```
import Header from "./ProductHeader.module.css";
.
.
.
<div className="col-12" className={Header.title} ></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like

```
<div className={`col-12 ${Header.title}`}"></div>
```

This way you can string and variable together in any attribute

You can also use it conditionally

```
<div className={`col-12 ${someCondition ? Header.title : Header.subTitle}`}></div>
```